# How do i retrieve browsers history in python django?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I want to display all the Internet History Information of a system using Python?

Comment: I hope this is an academic question and not something you're actually being paid to do...

Comment: It's not an academic question i'm trying to develop a web app for my self to retrieve internet browsing history in python.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope If this works,

Help to track given user is browsing a Django website

https://github.com/aaugustin/django-userlog

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you want, by design.

Comment: why? it's a process of retrieving ?

Comment: @hemanthpedhinti just ask yourself — would you be happy to know, that it's possible to steal the history of _yours_ browser? Some records in history can be used to identify you (for example social network profile address), and some records you probably don't want to be matched with you (for example, articles about some illness or medication).

Of course it would be inappropriate to design the web in a way allowing to someone to steal someone else's browsing history. So it's obviously impossible to do such things.